# redux action creator typing

Tags: typescript, redux

here's a question:

Imagine the following type:

```js
export type AppActionCreators = {
  foo: () => { type: string, payload: any} ;  // redux action
  bar: () => Promise<string>; // redux thunk
};
```

I'm trying to create a type for the dispatch function:

`export type DispatchFunc = Dispatch<AppActionCreators[ WHAT_DO_I_USE_HERE ] >;`

but I'm trying to figure what do I replace the `WHAT_DO_I_USE_HERE` with.

The end result I want is, I want dispatch to be able to take ANY child of AppActionCreators as an argument, like so:

```js
const dispatch: DispatchFunc = ...
dispatch(foo());
dispatch(bar()).then(); // correct return types too
```

btw [Dispatch is part of redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/80bda95d58f46fb5f6cbf6996ea87d1dcf58a602/src/types/store.ts#L27).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZVX1m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame not exactly, the possibly params of dispatch will be functions that either return a redux action `{ type: '' }`, or a redux-thunk: `(getState, dispatch) => {}`.

In your snippet, you only support the first scenario.

Comment: Unless this is some kind of typescript exercise, I'd use redux-toolkit, it massively improved TS support so you don't have to do things like this yourself (no need to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: @timotgl this is not a typescript exercise I'm just trying to improve my types on the action creators of mine.

Specifically I want to improve the result of `dispatch` which has a type of `DispatchFunc` so I'm trying to fix the `DispatchFunc` type to ALSO work with redux-thunks which our project heavily relies on.

Any pointers on doing that?

Comment: Btw I don't think converting our whole app to use slices from redux-toolkit is an option at this point :/

Comment: @SudoPlz Got it. The "AnyAction" you get out of the box is not enough, you want to ensure that dispatch is only passed *your* actions. There might be some TS trickery to do that (create a union type from all the types of your action creators) - the question is, is that actually useful? Do you run the risk of passing something that is *not* an action creator to dispatch?

Comment: @timotgl that makes sense, and I think that's totally fine, because we don't use `dispatch` directly, instead we map actions to our components by using react-redux, so I'm not afraid of passing a non action to dispatch.

What I really need is to fix the return type, so that it's the actual return type of each dispatch. (either a result if it's a plain action, or a promise that contains a result).